# Why does the Iterable Object returned from String.matchAll() have a length of 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterable, for-of-loop

When using a Regular Expression to pull matches from a string with matchAll(), the resulting Iterable Object that is spread into an Array object with the spread operator shows nested arrays with multiple members.

```
const regexUpperCaseTo = /(?<=\x2d|\x5f)[a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
const testVar1 = [...str.matchAll(regexUpperCaseTo)]
```

when we print out testVar1 it shows:

```
[
  [ 's', index: 4, input: 'the-stealth-warrior', groups: undefined ],
  [ 'w', index: 12, input: 'the-stealth-warrior', groups: undefined ]
]
```

Similarly, being an iterable object, we can use a for/of loop to iterate over each element of the returned array.

```
[ 's', index: 4, input: 'the-stealth-warrior', groups: undefined ]
[ 'w', index: 12, input: 'the-stealth-warrior', groups: undefined ]
```

However, once we test each member for length, it returns 1.

```
console.log(testVar1.forEach(x => console.log(x.length)))
```

and in addition to this, when we try to access the members of each array beyond the 0th member it returns *undefined*.

What is going on here that each member returned only seems to consist of the first element?

Comment: What do you expect the length to be?

Comment: @JaromandaX That would be `x[0].length`

Comment: Named properties aren't counted in the length of an array, only properties with numeric indexes.

Comment: The array returned by matching a regexp contains one element for the whole match, and then elements for all the capture groups. Your regexp has no capture groups, so the only element is the full match.

Comment: The inner Array is a Array length 1 (with value "s" for example), but has groups, index and input properties on that array, but the array is still length 1 ... e.g. try `console.log(x.length, x.input, x.index, x.groups)` in your forEach

Comment: The arrays returned by the iterator are just like the array returned by `str.match()`.

Comment: @JaromandaX ahhh ok, i see the resulting array is just the properties being returned as an array, but each match returns an object. I'm still trying to understand why the first element has a property name of '0' but each succeeding object in the array has a property name?

Comment: See how the output has `index:` and `input:` ... i.e. they are properties (the `:` gives that away) - chromes console output is misleading, index, input and group are not elements of the array, they are properties of that array - try `console.log(testVar1);` in firefox, and you'll see

Comment: An Array is an object, and just like any object your can add properties to it as you like - as I said, in your forEach loop, if you log `x.input`, `x.index` and `x.groups` you'll see those property values

Comment: Right, but then why isnt the first element in the 'array' preceded by a '0:' as such --> [ 0: 's', index: 4, input: 'the-stealth-warrior', groups: undefined ] ?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal (and has nothing to do with the iterator that `matchAll` returns). Each match - just like those returned from `.match()` and `.exec()` - is an array object with the whole match and the captured groups as elements.

Additionally, the array has some special properties like `.index`, `.input` and (since ES2018) `.groups`. See also [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295657/1048572) or [Contents of a RegExp match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34789109/1048572).